# bowtie2 options when mapping stranded single end reads

Tags: rna-seq, read-mapping, bowtie2

I'm trying to map RNA-Seq reads generated using the `NEB Ultra Directional kit is first strand reversed` protocal. I'm using [bowtie-2.3.5_1](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/manual.shtml#default-mode-search-for-multiple-alignments-report-the-best-one) to align against the mus musculuous (mm10) genome.  The reads are single ended.

It seems that `--fr` and `--rf` are relevant only for paired end options. I tried these options as well as not specifying either (default).

E.g.

```
$ bowtie2 --fr \
        --threads 20 \
        --very-sensitive \
        -x /reference/mus_musculus/mm10/ucsc_assmebly/illumina_download/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome \
        -U trimmed_out/my_trimmed.fq.gz \
        -S bowtie_fr_1.sam

$ samtools sort -n -o bowtie_fr_sort_1.sam bowtie_def_1.sam
```

I then compared the output of `bowtie_rf_sort.sam` `bowtie_default_sort.sam` and `bowtie_fr_sort.sam`.  They are basically identical excluding the header.

**Question**:

Does strandedness matter in this alignment? Perhaps I should care about the `--nofw/--norc` options? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you taking transcripts as the reference? `--norc` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using mm10 as my reference (downloaded from Illumina).

Comment: Then you need an RNA-seq mapper, not bowtie2. STAR and HISAT2 should have options to enable strand specific mapping. I am not familiar with those, though.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how bowtie is not an rna-seq mapper? Per their website "Bowtie 2 is often the first step in pipelines for comparative genomics, including for variation calling, ChIP-seq, RNA-seq,"

Comment: Bowtie2 is not aware of splicing. For typical RNA-seq applications, you will want to use a splice-aware mapper, such as star and hisat2, which is specifically designed for RNA-seq. Tophat2 does use bowtie2 for mapping, but it is invoking bowtie2 in a non-standard way and is generally thought to be superseded by star and hisat2 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I repeat what user172818 says...don't waste your time on bowtie or tophat.  Use STAR or HISAT2, or a pseudoaligner like kallisto with a transcriptome.